# How to capture a Cake build failure within an Azure DevOps task?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, cakebuild

For the reasons that are beyond the scope of this discussion, I have the following Azure DevOps setup which is being used to build some .NET library:

1. An Azure DevOps Powershell task:

```
 - task: PowerShell@2
      displayName: 'My task'
      inputs:
        targetType: filePath
        filePath: 'build_cake.ps1'
        arguments: '<my arguments>'
```

2. The `build_cake.ps1` script, executed by the DevOps task, which invokes Cake passing it the `build.cake` script:

```
try {
    Invoke-Expression "& <invoke Cake with build.cake>"
}
catch {
    exit 1;
}
```

3. The `build.cake`script which sets up some parameters and calls `Build.RunDotNetCore`:

```
Build.SetParameters(...);
Build.RunDotNetCore();
```

The `RunDotNetCore` call internally executes the `dotnet build` command. When that build fails for whatever reason, the error is not captured and/or propagated all the way back, so the Azure DevOps task `(1)` still happily reports successful execution.

I'm looking for a way to fix this.

At this point I'm not even sure whether the issue/solution is on the Cake side or on the Powershell side.

As my example shows, I have tried to wrap `Invoke-Expression` in a try/catch block but that didn't fix anything. I have also tried checking the `$LASTEXITCODE` code right after the `Invoke-Expression` call. (I guess `$LASTEXITCODE` is not supposed to be set anyway, since I'm invoking an external application and not a commandlet.)

To be clear, I'm not looking for an alternative solution (for example, to replace the existing setup with an equivalent Cake Azure DevOps task). I need to fix this particular setup with minimal changes, if possible.

Comment: The cake build should fail if task fails (unless something other was specified) I think the DevOps PS tasks have a 'fail on error' setting or something like that. I'm never sure if these are on or off by default.

Comment: Am I right in saying that Cake.Recipe is being used here? Or some variant of it? Are you able to replicate this problem on a public repository that we could take a look at?

Comment: on the `catch` block you could throw an `Exception` in order to stop execution of the cake. `if (!variable.Success) { throw new Exception(variable.ErrorText); }`

Answer (score 0):

The boostrapper I'm using looks like this and is confirmed working with Azure DevOps

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'

dotnet tool restore
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { exit $LASTEXITCODE }

dotnet cake @args
if ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0) { exit $LASTEXITCODE }
```

Above assumes your using a .NET tool manifest to version Cake, if you have Cake installed already on the agent you can skip the `dotnet tool restore` part.

Versioning Cake with a tool-manifest is preferred though as that ensures same version of Cake used locally and remote.

Installing Cake via tool manifest is done using dotnet cli in your repository root.

```bash
dotnet new tool-manifest
dotnet tool install Cake.Tool
```

and then add & commit in the `.config/dotnet-tools.json` file created.

Then when cloning the repo it's

```bash
dotnet tool restore
dotnet cake
```

And it'll fetch and execute the right version of Cake.

Comment: Thanks, looks really simple, as it's supposed to be. Unfortunately, I'm forced to stick with the current (convoluted) setup and try to apply absolutely minimal changes to it.